# How to get rid of echo inside the apartment?

Tags: plumbing, sound-proofing, plumbing-fixture, acoustic

A water pipe inside the apartment burst and was repaired. Ever since, the place has acquired a nasty echo. Everything resounds and we have to talk louder to be heard. Is there any solution to get rid of this echo?

Comment: What else changed as part of the repair? What was touched during the repair?

Comment: @longneck It was just the plumbing that got fixed.

Comment: Something else must have changed. Where was the leak? In the wall? Then they must have cut open the wall to get at the time. Again, what was touched during the repair?

Comment: @longneck I don't know what else was touched. Yes, the leak was in the wall.

Answer (score 2):

Have the room's contents changed? Irregular surfaces diffuse sound more effectively, as do soft surfaces. Wall hangings, bookcases (especially if the books aren't all lined up with each other), carpets, furniture and people all absorb some sound energy and change the sound of a room.

Comment: The room contents have not changed. I will try furnishing it with items you mention.

Answer (score 1):

Probably as a result of opening the wall to repair the plumbing, the wall facing was rebuilt.

You might try texturing the wall and repainting it with a non-glossy paint.  Just matching the other walls should be good enough.

Also, if you have not yet returned all wall coverings, tapestries, paintings, and furniture to that wall or carpet to the floor, the room will sound much "brighter".

Comment: The wall was repainted but the house wont stop echo'ing. Can you please elaborate on "not yet returned all wall coverings" ?

Comment: @moonstar2001:  Probably the wall had paintings and photos hung on it and furniture against the wall?  Just put them back like before the wall was redone.

Answer (score 1):

As said above, sound bounces around on hard surfaces. To calm the echo down you need to use a combination of diffusion and absorption.

Diffusion is what causes the sound to bounce in different directions, ie a blank wall will reflect the sound in the same direction which causes it to come straight back to your ears, but if you put a book shelf in the way the sound will bounce away from your ears.

Absorption is where the sound is prevented from reflecting. The most effective furniture here would be sofas, cushions and other soft furnishings. You can also make a difference with curtains and canvas paintings.

Hope this helps.

Antony greaves
Head of audio production
Academy of contemporary music

Comment: Thanks. Does the fabric of the curtains matter?

Comment: The heavier the curtains the more sound they will absorb, but otherwise the material doesn't make a huge difference.